# SUMIF criteria string with spaces?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

How do I get the criteria part of a `SUMIF` formula to recognize a string that contains spaces?

For example:

```
A       B   
Tim     1   
Tim (4) 2  
Tim     3   
Tim (4) 4
```

In here, I want to sum up all the `Tim (4)`'s. `=SUMIF(A1:A4,"Tim",B1:B4)` works giving me `4`, but `=SUMIF(A1:A4,"Tim (4)",B1:B4)` doesn't (should give me `6`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't the space, it's the brackets `()`. In regular expressions, they [are treated as special characters](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/List_of_Regular_Expressions). Instead, try

> `=SUMIF(A1:A4,"Tim \(4\)",B1:B4)`

In other words, escape the brackets using backslashes. Alternatively, disable regex in search patterns in the Calc settings.

Comment: The checkbox to disable regex is found by Tools→Options→OpenOffice Calc→Calculate→UNcheck the box "Enable regular expressions in formulas"

Comment: this indeed works, thanks a lot, both of you! i enabled regex to use wildcards unfortunately. i'll just use this workaround